# Mistakes in Bredon's book "Topology and Geometry"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I am preparing the notes for a course in Algebraic Topology, so I decided to borrow some of the material from the classical (and wonderful) book by G. Bredon [Topology and Geometry](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387979267).

Looking at the part regarding the orientation of a topological $n$-manifold $M^n$, at page 341 we find the following well-known result, with its usual proof (Proposition 7.1):

[image]

So far, so good. However, after five pages we find what follows:

[image]

This makes me confused, for at least two reasons:

**Point 1.** The Note after the statement of Proposition 7.10 does not make any sense to me. As defined, the symbol ${}_2G$ denotes the $2$-torsion part of the abelian group $G$, so if $G$ is torsion-free (for instance, if $G=\mathbf{Z}$) then ${}_2G=0$. This is clearly very different from the free-product $G \ast \mathbf{Z_2}$ (here $\ast$ seems to denote the free-product, see pages 158-159).

**Point 2.** In Corollary 7.11, take $A=\{x\}$ and $G=\mathbf{Z}$. Then, when $M$ is not orientable one finds $H_n(M, \, M-\{x\}, \, \mathbf{Z})=0$, and this contradicts Proposition 7.1, that yields the (correct, as far as I know) result      $H_n(M, \, M-\{x\}, \, \mathbf{Z})= \mathbf{Z}$.

> **Question.** Are the issues risen in Points 1, 2 above really mistakes in Bredon's book, or perhaps am I missing something trivial?

Comment: I guess $*$ might be a typo, it would rather be some sort of $\otimes$.

Comment: I suspect that the words "orientable along $A$" mean something like "a neighbourhood of $A$ is orientable", in which case corollary 7.11 would be correct

Comment: @DenisNardin: yes, essentially the meaning is that (see p. 342), and in fact he proves that $M$ is orientable if and only if $M$ is orientable along every compact subset (Proposition 7.6). However, I do not see how Corollary 7.11 can be correct, say for $A=\{x\}$: for *every* $n$-manifold (orientable or not) we must have $$H_n(M, \, M-\{x\}, \, \mathbf{Z})= \mathbf{Z},$$
or am I missing something?

Comment: Every point has an orientable neighborhood (say, a ball), hence $M$ is always orientable along $\{x\}$, so corollary 7.11 says that for every manifold $M$ the formula you give holds.

Comment: Ah, ok for this, thanks. If $A$ is compact and convex in $\mathbb{R}^n \subset M$, then Proposition 7.1 says that $$H_n(M, \, M-A, \, \mathbf{Z})= \mathbf{Z}.$$ So we are saying that $M$ is always orientable in a neighborhood of $A$ in that case?

Comment: Also it seems that Bredon indicates with $\ast$ what I would call $\mathrm{Tor}_1$, so in particular $A\ast \mathbb{Z}/n$ is exactly the $n$-torsion of $A$.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is true for any compact subset with a simply connected neighborhood (to see an example where this is not true, take the latitude in a torus)

Comment: Well, at page 158 it also indicate by $*$ the free product, and in a book of 550 pages it is not easy to understand where the same notation indicates two very different things. Now it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @DenisNardin: maybe you meant the latitude (= equator) in a Moebius strip? The torus is globally orientable, so I guess it is orientable along *every* compact subset...

Comment: Ugh, sorry. Yes, of course I meant a Möbius strip.

Comment: These matters are also well-covered elsewhere, e.g., in Dold's "Lectures on Algebraic Topology" where one can check when in doubt.

Comment: Find mistakes?  Look for errata that already exist.  For example, on the author's web page, or the publisher's web page.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Bredon died in 2000, and there is no webpage available. On the Springer's webpage there is no errata, either. Actually, on the web I found nothing (well, maybe I did not look well enough).

Comment: Roland van der Veen used to have errata in Dutch at http://staff.science.uva.nl/~riveen/AT_files/errata.pdf (link now broken). His new website is http://www.rolandvdv.nl/, but when I asked about the errata several years ago, he informed me that they had sadly been lost in the migration to a new server. Nonetheless, I can inform him of the existence of this question on the off chance that he can help in some way.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Star (in older topology texts) often indicate torsion product of abelian groups, that is, $A * B := \operatorname{Tor}_{\Bbb Z}(A, B)$. Usually it is clear from the context whether free product or torsion product is meant.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this (old) notation.

Comment: (This notation is also used in Spanier's text, for example.)

Comment: And Munkres!...

Comment: I'm not a specialist in Algebraic Topology, and my background on these basic topics is mainly from Massey's and Hatcher's books, where I never found this notation for $\mathrm{Tor}_1$ (at least, as far as I can remember). I am actually quite surprised that it seems to be rather common in older textbooks.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I'm allegedly a specialist in Algebraic Topology, and I didn't know either, so don't feel too bad :)

Comment: Bredon carefully defines A*B on page 278 in a section called More homological algebra and even says that it is often denoted Tor(A,B).

Comment: Yes, but again: the book is 550 pages long, one that is just interested in one topic cannot read carefully all of it.  Since at page 158 Bredon uses $*$ to indicated to free product, I supposed (maybe ingenuously) that this notation would have been kept in all the book, even because I never met the notation $*$ for $\mathrm{Tor}_1$ before.

Answer (score 9):

I think that you are missing the definition of  'orientable along $A$'.  I haven't got that book of Bredon to hand, but presumably 'orientable along $A$' means that if you move a local orientation of $M$ around a closed path that stays in $A$ then it will come back to the same local orientation.  In particular, in the case when $A$ is a single point, then $M$ will always be orientable along $A$, regardless of whether $M$ is orientable or not, so the case that you view as wrong doesn't arise.

I agree with Denis T's interpretation of the notation $A*B$.

Comment: Yes, definitely I was confused about the definition of "orientable along $A$". And I was unaware of the old notation $A*B$ for $\mathrm{Tor}_1(A, \, B)$.